# Align nav bar in the center

Tags: css, navigation

[image: Navigation bar]

Hi I am trying to have a nav bar in the middle on the top of the page. I have tried text alignment, align items as center, but I had no luck so far,
Does anyone know how to align this nav menu in the middle of the page?

```css
/* Clearfix */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}


/* Basic Styles */

body {
  background-color: #ece8e5;
}

nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20%;
  background: #da6548;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #da6548;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 5 px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}

nav li {
  /* display: inline; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-block
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}

nav li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  background-color: #8c99a4;
}

nav a#pull {
  display: none;
}


/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    height: auto;
  }
  nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
  }
}


/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #283744;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a#pull:after {
    content: "";
    background: url('http://media02.hongkiat.com/responsive-web-nav/demo/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
  }
}


/*Smartphone*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  nav li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
  }
}


/* nav bar until here */
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This site is really weird. If I post such a question I would be downvoted 35 times per minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin: auto;` to your nav element:

```css
/* Clearfix */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}


/* Basic Styles */

body {
  background-color: #ece8e5;
}

nav {
  margin: auto;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20%;
  background: #da6548;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #da6548;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 5 px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}

nav li {
  /* display: inline; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-block
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}

nav li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  background-color: #8c99a4;
}

nav a#pull {
  display: none;
}


/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    height: auto;
  }
  nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
  }
}


/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #283744;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a#pull:after {
    content: "";
    background: url('http://media02.hongkiat.com/responsive-web-nav/demo/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
  }
}


/*Smartphone*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  nav li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
  }
}


/* nav bar until here */
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to get rid of "float" and use flex instead, it's much simple and powerful and easy to deal with.

**CSS**

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 75px;
    background: #3c7eca;
    gap: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
nav a {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    background: #d86649;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks but if I apply this, it's not responsive anymore. I can't find the menu on mobile